# Got this error when knitting word doc using R mark down

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am getting this error when knitting word doc using r markdown. Checked my code several but couldn't find anything. Kindly help. Thanks
output file: Midterm.knit.md

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: yes

Note however that the HTML output will not be visible in non-HTML formats.

Execution halted
```

Comment: You have to include a minimal example code in your Question that reproduces this Error.

Answer (score 2):

One of your code chunks will be producing an HTML output. As you haven't provided a producible example, it is hard to know exactly which one, but it will likely be an interactive graph or map.

The reason this stops the compiling is that it is not possible to include HTML within a Word document. Word documents require static images. The following code will produce your error:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5))
```
````

To make this work, the easiest way is to just output to an HTML document:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Great guess! Your answer saved me quite some time, although I work with pdf :-D